# Max Level Number of Accounts in an Account Hierarchy

Tags: governorlimits, account, hierarchy, max

I couldn't find this in the documentation, but what is max Level number of accounts in an Account Hierarchy. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no effective limit.

However, it becomes impractical to deal with SObject hierarchies (not just an Account hierarchy) that are more than 5 levels deep due to formulas and SOQL/SOSL being limited to traversing upwards a maximum of 5 levels.

Comment: Thanks so much.